# How can I add and compile mongoc source code in projects and using locally (CMakeList config)

Tags: c++, c, libmongoc

I want to add mongoc source code to My project then compile, build and use it locally without installing libmongoc on the system(Ubuntu). I want My project source code to be portable without having to install any library dependencies like mongoc in the target development system and be a cross platform project.

How to configure the CMakeList file (or any other)?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: If you have the source, (.c and .h files) then include them in the make file just like any other source files.  _[Read this.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Spec-Files.html)_, and _[this](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/)_.

Comment: (1) install it locally using usual cmake installation procedure; (2) configure CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to include newly installed location; (3) use `find_package(libmongoc-1.0 1.15 REQUIRED)`;